# Spare Ribs: spacing out the soak and the grill

Tags: ribs

A specific recipe I like for preparing ribs involves a slow four hour soak at 250 degrees in the oven and then a grilling period. I was wondering, how badly is it going to affect the end result if I do the four hour soak the day before, and then placing them in the refrigerator to be grilled the next day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will have almost no impact (if any) provided you wrap them well using a cellophane wrap. This is also a good opportunity to apply a rub to the meat.

Comment: was planning to apply the rub before the soak, is that what you mean? and thanks!

Comment: @Dave, I'm pretty sure he is referring to applying the rub during the period it is waiting in the refrigerator(after the soak).

Comment: Applying the rub before the soak would cause the rub to wash off. If you apply the rub during the hold period, in the fridge, it will have the max impact.